# using cpanel database after copy it to local machine

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to shadow a live website to my local machine, I have finished all the copy thing for home folder and database from **cpanel**.

So far, I didn't make any change on code part, and just installed xampp and set up phpmyadmin.

after I set the localhost, and loaded the local page then below message displayed.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
mysql_connect() in F:\htdocs\ramtaps\includes\php_library.inc:41 Stack
trace: #0 F:\htdocs\ramtaps\includes\php_library.inc(19):
phpLibrary->createGlobalDatabaseConnection() #1
F:\htdocs\ramtaps\includes\php_library.inc(469):
phpLibrary->__construct() #2
F:\htdocs\ramtaps\includes\config\master.php(859):
include('F:\\htdocs\\ramta...') #3 F:\htdocs\ramtaps\index.php(4):
include('F:\\htdocs\\ramta...') #4 {main} thrown in
F:\htdocs\ramtaps\includes\php_library.inc on line 41
```

So I looked into the code and it said that `mysql_connect` is deprecated.

I am pretty new one this field and tried few things and they didn't work so far.

If anyone advises me regarding on this, I would really appreciate.

Comment: ,mysql_connect was removed and now you have to use mysqli_connect. Your database is not connected to the site.Check your Xammpp is working or not.If yes then  Start the Apache and MySql. Hope you created the database on the http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and uploaded the database. then you have to check the database code on your site.

Comment: After import the database you have to  change the  details in the your code. $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbnme";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although you did not mention your PHP version, it is obvious that you are using PHP with version > 7

`mysql_connect` was removed in PHP 7.0.0 and above

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

either install older version of PHP, or change your code

and maybe this is usefull for you http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Thank you kindly. just remember I did post a question here.